# How to fix error while installing AST-View on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to install AST-view plugin on Eclipse.

It visualizes the AST (abstract syntax tree) of a Java file open in the editor. And this can be installed in Eclipse Marketplace as follows:

[image]

I just clicked on *install* button. And I just followed default step.(e.g. Accept -> Next -> ...)

However, error message displayed and I cannot find the cause by reading messages:

[image]

***If you know the solution or other strategies to visualize AST of Java file on Eclipse, please let me know! Thanks :)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that at least version 3.18.0 of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plug-in is required.

This version of the plug-in is in Eclipse core 4.12 which is part of the Eclipse 2019-06 release (the current release at the time of writing). Older versions of Eclipse will not be able to install this plug-in.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the version of Eclipse that I use. My Eclipse version is Eclipse Photon which is version 4.8. Then could you explain me what is the cause of that error?

Comment: 4.8 is too old. This code will only run on the current Eclipse 2019-06